# Change WOL port

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, wake-on-lan

I have two PCs (both running Windows 10) that connected to my router, both use port 9 for WOL.

I want to be able to wake them from WAN, so I must to configure port-forwarding in my router, but because both use same port, its impossible.

Is there any way to change the WOL port of my  PCs?

Comment: I have integrated my answer as you wished me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken, the fact that both use the same port is not a problem at all. The reason is that, when you send the [magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), it must include the MAC address of the ethernet card it is addressed to. It cannot be done with individual IP addresses because, by definition, a sleeping pc does **not** have an IP address, so a MAC address is used instead. The packet reaches **all** machines on the LAN, which then check the destination MAC address: if it does not match their own MAC address, the magic packet is simply discarded. The machine whose MAC address instead matches the destination MAC address, begins the wake-up procedure.

So you have no conflict whatsoever.

**EDIT**

What I am suggesting is actually slightly different. I suggest that you use port 8855 for pc1, and port 8856 for port2. Both of them should be forwarded to port 9, but now, since the entrance port is different (8855 vs 8856) the router will use a different MAC address in the two cases. Then, only the pc with MAC address matching that of the magic packet will be awaken, even though the magic packet is always sent to port 9: that's because it is sent to port 9 of two different MAC addresses.
This way, with two distinct commands, to port 8855 or 8856, you can awake either (or both) of the two pcs.

Comment: No, I am not wrong. We must to set port-forwarding to specific IP, and then **bind** it to MAC address in the ARP table of the router. Otherwise it will not work (I test it). So the port must be unique for the port-forwarding..

Comment: @nrofis Sleeping pcs have no IP address: let me quote, Wikipedia, `the IP-address (layer 3 in the OSI model) is not used`.

Comment: Its true, and because of that you must to bind the IP to the MAC in the ARP table of the router. When the router trying forward the income WOL packet, it looks an the ARP and see what is the MAC address of destination...

The router works like that:
1. Listening to port 9 incoming UDP packets
2. Looking the port forwarding configuration and see the destination IP.
3. Looking the ARP table to convert that IP to MAC address.
4. Forward the packet the the MAC address.

So the IP is important to the router, even if PC is sleeping.

Comment: Maybe you will understand with example. Take a look at this: http://www.rtsecurity.com/kb/net/tplink_wol.php

Comment: @nrofis Yes, I have seen it. You still do not need to change the WOL port, because the magic packet contains the MAC address of the pc to be woken up, so that no confusion is possible.

Comment: But its not working. Only my first computer that configure like that is WOL. Both have the same settings, and if I change the port-forwarding IP to the second one (with the ARP table), it wake up but the first is not. So I able to wake only one PC at time. If the router was allow me to port-forwarding the magic packet to broadcast address it works fine.

Comment: @nrofis  You should forward port 8855 to one pc, and port 8856 to the other pc. Then you may give two commands, and wake up both pcs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32593/discussion-between-nrofis-and-mariusmatutiae).

Comment: His solution is the correct one, if it works you should mark this as answered.

Comment: @Linef4ult If you are talking to nrofis, you should preface your message with `@nrofis`, otherwise he will not receive it.  If instead you are talking to me, can you explain what you mean by `his solution`? Cheers.

Comment: Was @nrofis I intended it for.